# FreeTDS - TSQL fails when password given in option, but succeeds when typed?

Tags: t-sql, ubuntu, odbc, freetds

I'm trying to connect to a MS SQL Server trough PHP 5.6 with an Ubuntu 16.04 server. I'm forced to use this version of PHP, in order to assure compatibility with an 'ancient' application.

I installed PHP 5.6 and its modules (pdo, pdo_mysql, readline, etc.) trough **ondrej's PPA** without any trouble, but I wasn't able to find and install the 'mssql.so' module package needed for the application I'm trying to make work.

That's why I decided I would use **ODBC (and PDO_ODBC) drivers** in order to connect to the database.

In order to do so, I installed **freetds** with **unixodbc** and configured my files like this :

'odbcinst.ini' file :

[image]

'odbc.ini' file :

[image]

and finally the 'freetds.conf' file :

[image]

Ok, I guess all my files are well configured, but the next part starts to be a bit weird, let me explain you : when I try to **connect to the MS SQL database using tsql** and **not giving the password in option** but typing it when asked, the connexion works :

[image]

But when I try to **give the same password as an option** (-P), it doesn't work (I tried it at least 10 times with the correct password) !!!

[image]
--> tsql failed to open a session for the user 'WIPSOS-PHP'

**The same problem happens** when I try to **use isql with one of my connectors** I configured in the 'odbc.ini' file :

[image]

It seems to be **related to the password**, but I can't find the problem, can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a partial answer, and it was effectively related to the password: it seems like **special characters are not well interpreted** when present in the password given for the -P option of the tsql command.

Therefore, **depending on you shell**, you have to **escape these characters** in the string which completes an option. In my case, using bash, I had to use the '\' to escape the special character :

```
tsql -S hostname -D Database -U User -P pa\$\$word
```

And it now works!

[image]

But when I try to escape the special characters with '\' in the 'odbc.ini' file, it still doesn't seem to work :

[image]

My next question is : **'How to escape a special character in a '.ini' file ?'** or **'Is there something wrong in my configuration ?'**

EDIT: I know it was a long time ago, but I had a configuration problem related to the hostname in the "freetds.conf" file. In fact, I was using the server's local network DNS name instead of its IP adress(which works).

I hope my issue will at least help some people, it isn't easy to deal with TSQL and FreeTDS...